# Return false success in $.ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery version 1.6.2 and I can't redirect my users to the main page after login. Actually, I can, but if I do this, I can't display the "error messages".

Can you help me?

My jQuery code:

```
$(".enviar").click(function() {
    var email = $(".postEmail");
    var setEmail = email.val();
    var senha = $(".postSenha");
    var setSenha = senha.val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "actions/logar.php",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: "email="+ setEmail +"&senha="+ setSenha,
        success:function(data){
            if(data == 'true'){
                window.location.href="home";
            } else {
                $(".resposta").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Where ".enviar" is my submit button and ".resposta" is the div where I'll display the error message.

My PHP code:

```
        if(!$AccountDAO->Registrado()){
            $postEmail = addslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));
            $postSenha = addslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['senha'])));

            if ( !preg_match( '/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', $postEmail )){
                echo '<span class="error">O seu e-mail parece inválido</span>';
                exit();
            } elseif ( strlen($postSenha) < 4 ) {
                echo '<span class="error">Digite uma senha com quatro ou mais caracteres</span>';
                exit();
            } 

            $validarUsuario = $SQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `c_usuarios` WHERE `email` = :email AND `senha` = :senha");
            $validarUsuario->bindParam( ':email', $postEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $validarUsuario->bindParam( ':senha', hash('sha512', $postSenha), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $validarUsuario->execute();

            if( $validarUsuario->rowCount() == true ){

                $dadosUsuario = $validarUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $dadosUsuario['uid'];
                echo 'true';

            } else {

                echo '<span class="error">O e-mail ou a senha estão incorretos</span>';

            }
        }
?>
```

I already try "return true" instead of "echo "true"", but i get the same result: nothing. =(

Alright, sorry 4 my english (I'm Portuguese, as you can see) and this is my first time without Google Translate. Ah, if is possible too, rate my language skills, please? HAHAH

Ok, seeya!

***Update***

After many debbugings(?), I came to the conclusion that all the code that follows

```
            $dadosUsuario = $validarUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $dadosUsuario['uid'];
```

doesn't execute. Indeed, the "true" (from echo) execute normaly, but the "true" (string) has a line break. See:

[image: screenshot]

I don't understand! :S
If I move the `echo true´ to the top of my source, it displays normally, without line break.

Comment: So does the AJAX request ever return at all? If you set an alert() in the success function does it ever get called?

Comment: what is your `data` in `success` when you return `"true"`?

Comment: View the data that is being returned to the AJAX call using a tool like FireBug (it can monitor .NET AJAX requests and show both data sent and retrieved). Then the problem should be easy to find. Your English is much better than my Portuguese :-)

Comment: Language skills = very good. And although I don't speak Portugese, I can't speak Spanish as well as you speak English. :D

Comment: Is that all that is in your PHP file? Are you getting any server-side errors?

Comment: Why are you setting async to false? If you need a synchronous post, why use ajax?

Comment: does your `success` handler gets called?

Comment: +TaylorOtwell: Yes; +William: The "true" in success function represents the return value from php; +pst: I already using Google Chrome, and I do not how to use the "debugger" panel. And, thank you for rated! =); +Fred: Thank you for rating, too! So, I have more code in my PHP file, but i think it isn't necessary paste here. Is it? +Alien: I use async to debug, sorry; +3nigma: Handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any avascript errors? Are you using Firebug or Google Chrome console? If yes try to log your response without any redirection. I've written simple ajax-request and according to the response make(or do not) redirect. All works fine. 
Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form action="">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "show=1",
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data=='true'){
                            window.location.href="other-page.html";
                        } else {
                            $("#wrapper").append(data);
                        }
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

And very simple PHP:

```
if($_POST['show']==1)
    echo 'true';
else
    echo '<span class="error">Error</span>';
```

Whatever, try to debug response from your server. 
Sorry for lots of code, but can't see important difference between your and my ones. Maybe you will.:)
I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Hello, Ruslan. Thanks for you reply too. So, your example is working, but, is very similar to mine script, really. I used the Chrome console to debbuging and with or without redirect, the console doesn't display errors. Any suggestions? If is very necessary, I can post the full php source here - but, how I can do this?

Comment: Hello again, @Ruslan Polutsygan. Now I posted the full php source. If possible, check it. :)

Comment: Either you php-code always echos 'true' or you have something wrong with you js-code. Try to log into console response from server. Remove (or comment) all the code in callback function and write `console.log(data)`. Then try to write in the very top of you php-file `echo 'true'; die();` or `echo 'error'; die();`. Run your application with opened console and look what heppens. What is the value of `data` in different cases? Experiment, experiment, experiment :)

Comment: Hello, @Ruslan Polutsygan. If I echo "true", print True in the console; If I echo "error", print Echo in the console. I think the problem is in php code.

Comment: Does redirect(or html-code applying) works well if `echo 'true'` (or `echo 'error'`) is hardcoded in the php-file? If yes then problem is definitely in the php-code. 
Try to log into console data which is recieved from server. Also you could add some unique 'id' to each echo operation to determine where exectly script stops running.
Else try to run your php-code directly from browser (not using ajax). Debug, debug, debug:)

Comment: Hi, @Ruslan Polutsygan. Finally, I debug a lot! So, look the main post, please. =)

Comment: Hi, Guilherme. Linebreak may be printed because in one of your files there is an empty line after `?>`(php close tag) or between `?>` and `<?php`. This code is interpreted as direct output (the same as `echo "\n"`). Also the question: are you using `php close tags` in the end of any file? If yes remove them. You do not need them. If no then try to find the file with `?>__linebreak__<?php`. **UPD** also it may be in the top of the file before open php tag

Comment: Hello, @Ruslan Polutsygan. So, the problem is on the included file. He do one BOM (Byte Order Mark) on the top, changing the TRUE result to something like this: "\n\n TRUE". Understand? Thank you for the help, mate! =) <3

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the domaine name. Like `window.location.href="http://example.com/home";`

Comment: i think that is not the problem

Comment: Hello, Vizath. Thank you for you reply. So, what 3nigma said is truth.  Nothing happened with this change. =/